# Pandas.DataFrame.Plotで描写した折れ線グラフについて、x軸の途中から色を変えたい。

Tags: python, python3, pandas

Pandas.DataFrame.Plotで描写した折れ線グラフについて、x軸の途中から色を変えたいです。
以下で例えばx軸が3以上の場合に折れ線の色を赤色に変えるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。
同様の質問が見つからず、ご教授下さい。

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'x-axis':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y-axis':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
df.plot(x='x-axis',y='y-axis')
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4):

これでどうでしょう？([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424889/matplotlib-changing-the-colour-of-the-line-after-certain-point-in-index))

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = {'x-axis':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y-axis':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
N = 3.0
ax = df['x-axis'].plot()
df.loc[df.index >= N, 'x-axis'].plot(color='r', ax=ax)
ax = df.plot(x='x-axis',y='y-axis')
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 有難うございます、解決しました。axの引数を使って重ね合わさなければならないのですね。